# A particular image is not getting pulled from Docker Hub - jwilder/nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-machine

I am able to happily pull most images, except the following:

```
docker pull jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

The following is the error message:

> Using default tag: latest
>   Pulling repository docker.io/jwilder/nginx-proxy
>   Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/jwilder/nginx-proxy/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like pulling this particular image is affected due to many issues mentioned here - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15603

Docker 1.9 could potentially solve this.

I solved it by creating a new docker machine and pulling the image from there. Then did a `docker save` and `docker load` onto my original docker-machine.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue as mentioned on https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15603#issuecomment-133151849

```
$ docker-machine stop default
$ docker images -q | xargs docker rmi
$ docker-machine start default
```